# How to edit multiple meshes once without joining?

Tags: mesh, edit-mode

Hi I am looking to edit multiple meshes without joining them.

I have selected all meshes and set origin to geometry because I want to do curved extrude. It is easy to do it in one mesh but I can't figure out how to do it to all of them. If I join them together and do curved extrude them the curve is towards the centre point which ruins the shape of most meshes except the one that is selected to be origin geometry.

[image: Picture 1]

Please see Picture 1: I would like to edit all the 2D round meshes and extrude them like the one on the right until I eventually close them (like the one in the middle). The problem is that I would like to do this with more than 1000 random spheres. I can't manipulate more than one image in the edit mode, where I would extrude the meshes to create the closed object like the one in the middle.

[image: Picture 2]

I have tried to join them all together and edit them but there is a problem because there is only one centre point and them when I extrude them and scale to 0.5x it usually closes the circle if the centre point is to the mesh but now they all move towards one centre point. Please see Picture 2.

I have even used the MultiEdit tool but it still joins all the meshes together, which is not what I want.

Please help and many thanks in advance.

Comment: This simply isn't possible. Why exactly do you want to do this? There is a good chance that what you want can be accomplished using a different tool/feature.

Comment: I'm new to blender. I have uploaded an SVG file from Illustrator and now I would like to extrude in a curved shape and finally close it to make 3D shape. But if I try to join and extrude and try to make it curved then it only does so towards the centre. Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Please see my comment below, where I have explained the problem as you suggested with a picture

Comment: Did you try setting the [Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) to the *Individual Origins* as already mentioned before scaling joined meshes ? It looks like that's the case to use it.

Comment: Thanks. That's great Pivot Point to Individual Origins was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i know what you want to achieve.

If you're trying to add a rounded edge to an extruded svg text/shape, then you can simply extrude the entire mesh and use [Bevel tool](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/meshes/editing/subdividing/bevel.html) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> in Edit mode with adjacent edges selected). If using it in Edit mode, the tool is interactive, i.e. change parameters while it's active.

Alternatively, before extruding change the [Pivot Point](https://www.blender.org/manual/ru/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/pivot_point/index.html) to *Individual Origins* in the 3D Viewport Header bar (by default, in the bottom of the 3D viewport).

Comment: Please see my answer above where I have tried to explain it in more details i.e. with pictures